# Routing Grpc using Grpc.Core

Tags: c#, grpc, envoyproxy

I want to prefix the url with a specific fragment like "/servicename/" such that I can route it in my envoy proxy, how do I do this using the client/channel interface from Grpc.Core?

My envoy routes traffic from 10001 to 50061 using:

```
            virtual_hosts:
            - name: grpc_service
              domains: ["*"]
              routes:
              - name: grpc_proxy
                match:
                  prefix: "/mygrpcservice" # I need the prefix to match this
                route:
                  # disable route timeout for streaming
                  timeout: 0s
                  auto_host_rewrite: true
                  prefix_rewrite: "/"
                  cluster: grpc_mygrpcservice
```

Currently my client is created using:

```
_client = new MyGrpcServiceClient(
    new Channel("localhost", 10001, ChannelCredentials.Insecure));
```

Envoy access log shows:

```
"grpc-csharp/2.31.0 grpc-c/11.0.0 (windows; chttp2)" "9f6e1ece-8b6c-4bcd-a367-b9c6e808618c" "mygrpc" "172.18.0.16:50061"
[2021-04-07T08:35:48.569Z] "POST /MyApp.MyGrpcService/GetMagicNumber HTTP/2" 0 DC 123 0 39921 - "-"
```

Comment: Adding custom prefixes to the paths is actually discouraged. See https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dotnet/pull/509#issuecomment-532314819, https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/14900 and https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dotnet/issues/110 for context.

Comment: quoting from https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/PROTOCOL-HTTP2.md: Some gRPC implementations may allow the Path format shown above to be overridden, but this functionality is strongly discouraged. gRPC does not go out of its way to break users that are using this kind of override, but we do not actively support it, and some functionality (e.g., service config support) will not work when the path is not of the form shown above.